# I have a figure made from a numpy array including five line graphs, how do I add a trendline for each graph?

Tags: python, trendline

I am working with a database of which the relevant data is loaded into a numpy array. Using the following code, I made a figure including five lines for five variables.

```
porosity = 0.35

df_plot = df_soilTemp[['Moisture litter layer','Moisture 3 cm','Moisture 20 cm','Moisture 50 cm','Moisture 100 cm']]/porosity

np_soilTemp = np.asarray(df_soilTemp)

t = np.asarray(df_soilTemp.index)

df_plot['Moisture litter layer'].where((df_plot['Moisture litter layer']>0.03) & (df_plot['Moisture litter layer']<1.0),
                                       np.nan,inplace=True)

df_plot['Moisture 3 cm'].where((df_plot['Moisture 3 cm']>0.03) & (df_plot['Moisture 3 cm']<1.0), np.nan,inplace=True)

df_plot['Moisture 20 cm'].where((df_plot['Moisture 20 cm']>0.03) & (df_plot['Moisture 20 cm']<1.0), np.nan,inplace=True)

df_plot['Moisture 50 cm'].where((df_plot['Moisture 50 cm']>0.03) & (df_plot['Moisture 50 cm']<1.0), np.nan,inplace=True)

df_plot['Moisture 100 cm'].where((df_plot['Moisture 100 cm']>0.03) & (df_plot['Moisture 100 cm']<1.0), np.nan,inplace=True)

f4 = df_plot.iplot(asFigure=True, layout=dict(yaxis=dict(title='Soil moisture content (m3/m3) '),
                                              xaxis=dict(title='Time (years) '), 
                                              title='Soil moisture variability over time at different soil depths', 
                                              legend_title='Soil depth'), width=2)

f4.show()
```

I want to add a trendline for every variable, how can I do this?

I tried something like this:

```
df_soilTemp_MA=df_soilTemp.rolling(window=17520).mean()
slope,intercept,r_val,p_val,error =linregress(df_soilTemp_MA['Moisture litter layer'])
print(slope)
```

### I hoped that this would give me a trendline for one of the five lines, but I get this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-a26336926e7a> in <module>
     12 
     13 df_soilTemp_MA=df_soilTemp.rolling(window=17520).mean()
---> 14 slope,intercept,r_val,p_val,error =linregress(df_soilTemp_MA['Moisture litter layer'])
     15 print(slope)
     16 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_mstats_common.py in linregress(x, y)
    123         if x.shape[0] == 2:
    124             x, y = x
--> 125         elif x.shape[1] == 2:
    126             x, y = x.T
    127         else:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
If relevant, I am working in Jupyter Notebook, since the data I am using is online.

Answer (score 1):

linregress is getting 2 parameters: x and y or 2 dimensional array which can be spilt to 2.
You seem to pass only 1 parameter which is a Pandas series with some values that I guess are the “y” that you want to see.
So my suggestion is that you add as “x” : np.arange(len(df_soilTemp_MA['Moisture litter layer'])) which is just 0,1,2…,len - 1.